# how to get all rows from csv file to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to get all rows from csv file to insert the data to MySQL database.
Now I have this csv file:

name1;country1
name2;country2

and to get the data I use PHP, like this:

```
<?php

$db_host = 'ip';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'pass';
$database = 'database_name';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass))
  die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
  die("Database doesn't exist");

$handle = fopen("csvfile.csv", "r");
if( $handle ) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT INTO table (name, country, updated) VALUES ('$data[0]',  '$data[1]', now())";     
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

It is working but only with the first row of the csv file. When I do the select of the table on MySQL the result is only the first row of the csv.
The second row is not inserting.

How Can I do to insert all the rows correctly?

Comment: forget php, just LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: but how I can do it if I want execute it from Ubuntu terminal every time that the csv file is modified?

Comment: I had thought use a cron that everytime that the csv is modified execute the php file.